# Hiding encryption key AES-256 in JAVA

Tags: java, encryption, jar, client-server, aes

As we now, a .jar file, we can open it and see the code and classes with any decompiler. Now suppose the following situation:

I developed a Client-Server application under JAVA, in both Client and Server, i used AES-256 for encrypting the data sent over internet. So, i give the "Client" to my friend. Now..  The question is... can he hack my Server knowing how are the packets received in the Client, treated, and sent back? I mean... encrypting the data when you have a revealed code, it's.. in vain, doesn't it?

The question is... what can i do to have the best security possible in the Server? does encryption work in this case ?

Thanks !!!

Comment: Related: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/09/27/keep-it-secret-keep-it-safe.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use encryption just to hide how your client-server protocol works. If you want your server to be secure, make it secure even when the client is in full control of what goes on.

As you've mentioned, it's easy to control the client: not just via decompilation, but also by running the client in a debugger (which can modify the contents of any object, modify control flow, etc.).

My points, then, are:

1. It's important to identify where the potential attack vectors are in your server, and address those. For example, if you want to be able to send a cookie to a client, which you want them to send back unaltered, you don't need encryption for that; just use HMAC.
2. If you actually really want to encrypt traffic between client and server, don't use straight AES (especially because it sounds like you're using a fixed key, which is insecure). You want to use a protocol designed for wire encryption, like TLS (SSL). Yes, really use TLS (including acquiring a certificate from a certificate authority); don't take shortcuts.

   The nice thing about TLS is that there are no shared secrets (such as keys) that you have to embed into your jar. So there is nothing you have to worry about hiding.

Comment: +1 for _"make it secure even when the client is in full control of what goes on"_ -- this is the ONLY possible answer, because it describes the real world.

Comment: Ok. So what u reccomend me is to (as u and Evgheni Crujcov said before) to have a strong validation on what comes to my server? i mean, i should not care about the client, hiding the packets and the protocol? The traffic and the packets have nothing TOP SECRET. But... my fear is about what could a hacker do to my Server, for example, sending querys or something like that. Im new in this, so if u can illustrate me the possible situations that could cause me problems, i would aprreciate that.

Comment: @Gerardo You should read the [OWASP Top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project). They're not the only things you have to defend against, but they're very common mistakes and very commonly exploited.

Comment: Why don't you examine an existing protocol first, e.g. TCP. TCP packets have fields, e.g. 2 fields of interest - SEQ and ACK. One machine sends a packet to another with SEQ:0, ACK:0, and lenght of 8 bytes. What are the expected values for the acknowledgement from the other machine. By TCP protocol, SEQ:8, ACK:0 (that is, the receiving machine is telling the sender that it now expects 8th byte and onward). But... what would happen if instead it sends SEQ:5? Should you resend it the 5th byte and onward? Should your server return some command invalid response? Or just throw an exception and die?

Comment: Basically what I was getting at is that, if a protocol expects specific values in the fields of the packet that goes between client and server, at specific times, it should check that what is coming, is what it expects, and not just blindly accept/attempt to accept any response.

Comment: @EvgheniCrujcov TCP is a little too low-level for what the OP's doing. I do agree that validation is very important and that everything that could be validated, should be.

Comment: Ok Thanks people. to everyone. Im checking that and if any doubts, i come back.

Answer (score 1):

If by him hacking your server you mean him meaning figuring out the protocol and contents of the packet that goes in, and then sending funky packets to make your server do unexpected things at unexpected times, the solution seems to be not as much encryption but strong validation. That is, your server should expect only a limited set of values in the incoming packets at each step of your protocol, and if some of the incoming packets do not conform to this/attempt to do something unexpected, they should be discarded.

Answer (score 1):

Your encryption is not going to allow you to hide the protocol/API/etc. that the client and server use to communicate with each other. By encrypting the data flowing between the client and server, you are preventing someone that is observing this traffic as it passes across the wire (presumably the internet) from snooping on the data.

One issue to keep in mind is that AES requires a password that is know by both the client and the server. If your password is hardcoded in the jar, then anyone that has the jar can snoop on any traffic between your server and anyone's client that connects to it. So, you need a secure way for the client and server to agree on the password to use for a given connection.

I suggest using an SSL-based technology for encrypting the data going on the wire (e.g., maybe you can simply use HTTPS as your protocol). Or perhaps use public key encryption.

It is hard to make a specific recommendation, given the lack of information about the communication pattern between client and server.